# error al pasar parametros a NODEJS desde REACTJS

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express.js

Estoy intentando hacer un componente que recoja los datos de los dos input y los pase al back de nodejs para hacer una sql. El problema que tengo es que al pasar un JSON no me detecta en el nodejs el parametro que paso. He probado pasando el JSON.stringfy pero nada. Adjunto codigo:

este es el componente login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getLogin } from '../routeApi';
import axios from 'axios'

class login extends Component {
 render() {
     /*if(this.props.data){
         var name = this.props.data.name;
         var pass= "images/"+this.props.data.image;
         
       }*/
       const  comprobarLogin = async () =>{
         const nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value
         const pass = document.getElementById('pass').value
         const json = {
             nombre: nombre,
             pass: pass
         }
        
         /*axios.post('http://localhost:4000/login', {
             firstName: 'Finn',
             lastName: 'Williams'
           });*/
         const loginRes = await getLogin(json)
         console.log(loginRes)
       }
      
     return (
         <section id="login">
             <div className="row">
                 <input type="text" placeholder="introduce el usuario" className="login-input" id="nombre"/>
                 <input type="password" placeholder="introduce la contraseña" className="login-input" id="pass"/>
                 <button onClick={comprobarLogin}>ACCEDER</button>
             </div>
         </section>
     )
 }
}

export default login;
```

este es el router en react con la funcion fetch

```
import axios from 'axios'
export const getLogin= async(jsonParams) =>{    
    console.log(jsonParams)
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/login',{
        method:"POST",
        headers: new Headers({'content-type': 'application/json'}),
        body: JSON.stringify(jsonParams)
    })

    
    return await res.json()
}
```

en la parte de nodejs en el fichero de routes tengo lo siguiente:

```
import {Router} from 'express'

const router = Router()

router.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("req ")
    console.log(req.body)
})

export default router
```

luego en app.js en el nodejs

```
import express from 'express';
import taskRoutes from './routes/task'
const app = express();

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cors())
app.use(taskRoutes)
app.use(express.json());

export default app
```

y luego la salida en el servidor node es la siguiente:

```
req 
{}
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Pasa que **req** es un objeto, no un JSON. Por eso te da error.

Si queres trabajar con el cuerpo de la peticion (osea con el json que envias dede el front), debes usar **req.body** , y no hace falta que lo parsees a json.

Saludos.

---

Osea seria:

```
router.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body) 
})
```

---

En el front te falto el content type para que puedas tomar los datos desde body:

```
const getLogin= async(jsonParams) =>{    
    console.log(jsonParams)
    const res = await fetch('/users',{
        method:"POST",
        headers: new Headers({'content-type': 'application/json'}),
        body: JSON.stringify(jsonParams)
    })
    return await res.json()
}
```

Comment: Hola @Karl kno primero muchas gracias por tu respuesta! he probado cambiando el metodo a lo siguiente router.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("req ")
    console.log(req.body)
})    el problema que tengo es que me devuelve  undefined y no entiendo el porque dado que se lo estoy pasando al body. Tambien he probado poniendo req.body.nombre pero al ser "body" undefinded obviamente no obtengo "body.nombre"

Comment: Recien veo como estas mandando la requests, ahi te edite la respuesta, para que veas un detalle.

Comment: he probado poniendo el content type y me sigue dando undefined en el node.js, el metodo que recoge la solicitus es el siguiente:   router.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("req ")
    console.log(req.body)
})

Comment: Ok, proba esto. Por que la libreria "body-paerser". Ya no se usa mas.  la linea `const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); ` sacala. y en lugar de `app.use(bodyParser.json());` usa  `app.use(express.json());` . Si sigue sin funcioanr, podrias actualizar el codigo que estas implementando en la pregunta?

Comment: Buenas, he probado y sigue sin funcionar, he actualizado la pregunta con el codigo actual que tengo. Si necesitas que ponga algo mas indicamelo, en principio es todo el codigo que tengo, gracias!!

Comment: ah, sabes que me falto pedirte, que agregues el middleware:  `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` Avisa.

Comment: vale ahora al menos no sale "undefined", ahora me sale lo siquiente:  req 
{}  actualizo la pregunta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136589/discussion-between-javier-lenza-and-karl-kno).